# Adding two panels to a JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I'm learning GUIs, and trying to place two panels side by side in a frame. Without giving you all of my code (it's for an assignment) can anyone give me any pointers as to why the below isn't working? (ControlPanel just doesn't display) I followed the tutorials, but can't see where I'm going wrong?

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Software");
    MainPanel m = new MainPanel();
    ControlPanel c = new ControlPanel(frame);

    frame.getContentPane().add(m, BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.getContentPane().add(c, BorderLayout.EAST);



    public class MainPanel extends JPanel {

    .......

    public MainPanel(){
    super();
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocus();
    }
}

    public ControlPanel(JFrame frame) {
    super();
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocus();
    }
}
```

Edit:

Rest of code:

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Software");
    MainPanel m = new MainPanel();
    ControlPanel c = new ControlPanel(frame);
    frame.getContentPane().add(c, BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.getContentPane().add(m, BorderLayout.EAST);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(m);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Which layout do you use?

Comment: You mean like BorderLayout etc? The only layout I have is as above, and then I use a boxlayout in the ControlPanel to lay some buttons out   setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

Comment: I thought this was the only layout I need (taken from above): 
frame.getContentPane().add(m, BorderLayout.WEST);
frame.getContentPane().add(c, BorderLayout.EAST);

Comment: This is the problem: `frame.setContentPane(m);` - you just replaced the content pane that contained both `c` and `m`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the layout of your frame to BorderLayout.

Use this:

```
frame.setlayout(new BorderLayout());
```

Moreover, if your frame is divided into exactly two equal halves, you may also use a GridLayout.

```
frame.setLayout(new GrigLayout(1,2)); // If the panels are side-by-side.
```

or

```
frame.setLayout(new GrigLayout(2,1)); //If the panels are vertically adjacent.
```

Comment: note: frame divided in two, JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, a, b) is nice too

Comment: hmmm...thanks @Hackerdashi, but still not working :( Will copy more code in above....

Comment: Got it, based on this, and the below answer - thanks so much!

Answer (score 4):

In your code, you are replacing the content panel of the `JFrame` with your instance of `MainPanel` :

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Software");
    MainPanel m = new MainPanel();
    ControlPanel c = new ControlPanel(frame);
    frame.getContentPane().add(c, BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.getContentPane().add(m, BorderLayout.EAST);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());// this has no use
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setContentPane(m);// here the content pane becomes the MainPanel
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

So as you already add things to the content pane, there is no need to reset it (also, I moved the `setLayout` to the content pane, instead of the `JFrame`)

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Software");
    MainPanel m = new MainPanel();
    ControlPanel c = new ControlPanel(frame);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(c, BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.getContentPane().add(m, BorderLayout.EAST);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thanks @Berger! This has led me to another problem....My main panel, takes keyboard input. That now doesn't work :( Could that be because I requestfocus() for Main panel, AND Control Panel?

Comment: @javapalava : could you edit your question with some details about this, or post another one with this problem ?

Comment: Sure :) I'm just trawling the web first to see if I can figure it out myself before I have to turn to this!

Answer (score 2):

Check this

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Software");
    MainPanel m = new MainPanel();
    ControlPanel c = new ControlPanel(frame);
    //getContentPane layout to BorderLayout
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(c, BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.getContentPane().add(m, BorderLayout.EAST);

    //you don't need it for now 
    //frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //frame.setContentPane(m);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Edit: Layout of ContentPane of JFrame returns JFlowLayout so thats why the below part doesn't work

```
.getContentPane().add(c, BorderLayout.WEST); 
frame.getContentPane().add(m, BorderLayout.EAST);
```